# MongoDb - add index on 'calculated' fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a query that includes an `$expr`-operator with a `$cond` in it.
Basically, I want to have objects with a timestamp from a certain year. If the timestamp is not set, I'll use the creation date instead.

```
{
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $cond: {
          'if': {
            TimeStamp: {
              $type: 'null'
            }
          },
          then: {
            $year: '$Created'
          },
          'else': {
            $year: '$TimeStamp'
          }
        }
      },
      <wanted-year>
    ]
  }
}
```

It would be nice to have this query using a index. But is it possible to do so? Should I just add index to both `TimeStamp` and `Created`-fields? Or is it possible to create an index for a `Year`-field that doesn't really exist on the document itself...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not possible

Indexes are stored on disk **before** executing the query.

**Workaround:** [On-Demand Materialized Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/)

You store in separate collection your calculated data (with indexes)

Comment: I was afraid ‘not possible’ would come up - even though I can’t see his ‘index stores before index’ explains why. The index needs to read every doc when it is first created and could create the calculated value at that point. The index needs to be refreshed every time a document is updated so again the calculated value could be updated. So I’m rooting for a new feature in 4.8I’ll check out the view feature though. We are ‘stranded’ on 3.6 but should of cause update soon anyway..

Comment: @Vegar Would be nice to preindex documents before quering. Btw: `$expr` not always uses indexes. For instance, if you index any field and use `$eq`/`$ne` operator to filter, it uses index! But if you use `$in` / `$gt` / `$lt`, etc.. now it doesn't... [SERVER-32549](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549)

Comment: Luckily I do have another filter criteria that is indexed so a colscan is not that bad in this case. I hope...  if it is, we’ll just start to store the correct year in the doc it self.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done today without precomputing that information and storing it in a field on the document. The closest alternative would probably be to use MongoDB 4.2's [aggregation pipeline-powered updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to precompute and store a `createdOrTimestamp` field whenever your documents are updated. You could then create an index on `createdOrTimestamp` that would be used when querying for documents that match a certain year.

What this would look like when updating or after inserting your document:

```
db.collection.update({ _id: ObjectId("5e8523e7ea740b14fb16b5c3") }, [
    {
        $set: {
            createdOrTimestamp: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {$gt: ['$TimeStamp', null]},
                    then: '$TimeStamp',
                    else: '$Created'
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

If documents already exist, you could also send off an `updateMany` operation with that aggregation to get that computed field into all your existing documents.

It would be really nice to be able to define computed fields declaratively on a collection just like indexes, so that they take care of keeping themselves up to date!